# Dynamic argument for @CacheEvict

Tags: java, spring, annotations, ehcache

I am implementing EHcache in my project and i have written a method that will remove all entries from the cache. The method works fine, here's the code snippet:

```
 public void removeEntriesFromCache(String cacheName){
    CacheManager.getInstance.getCache(cacheName).removeAll();
}
```

I am eventually going to expose this method as a rest service so that user could call the service along with cache name that needs to be invalidated. However, i would want to be able to do the same using @CacheEvict. I know i can do this:

```
 @CacheEvict(name ="myCache" , allEntries=true)
public void removeEntriesFromCache(){

}
```

But, this method will remove entries from just one cache , in this case it will remove all cache entries from "myCache". I want to be able to resolve the cache name dynamically at runtime as specified by the user.

Is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
@CacheEvict(name ="${cacheName}" , allEntries=true)
public void removeEntriesFromCache(String cacheName){

}
```

**OR**

```
@CacheEvict(name ="#cacheName" , allEntries=true)
public void removeEntriesFromCache(String cacheName){

}
```

Your suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[@CacheEvict](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html) documentation clearly states where you can use SpEl. You can't use SpEl in the name attribute, but you can inject `CacheManager` to the bean you are annotating now, get the `Cache` by name and clear it.

`cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear()`

Comment: You are right, documentation clearly states where we can use SpEI. I posted this question to know it there's any other approach to achieve this.

Comment: Check out `CacheAspectSupport` , there you can see the whole evaluation process. `processCacheEvicts` the relevant part. Changing this method would require quite a bit of coding, but you can specify your own `CacheResolver` in the annotation, from that you can access the method parameters and you can resolve the caches you want to evict. Hope that brings you closer to solve this.